# Rails 6 uniqueness validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Currently having trouble with the `validate_uniqueness_of` method on my model with a given scope.

Right now I have 3 tables:
User, College, UsersColleges (join between user and college)

```
User has_many :users_colleges
College has_many :users_colleges
UsersColleges belongs_to :user, :college
```

Right now, I am validating the uniqueness of the user_colleges, so that a user can only have 1 entry of the specified college.

`validates_uniqueness_of :college_id, scope: :user_id`

However, when updating my user with specific colleges, the validation fails -- `College has been taken`.
This behavior only happens for specific colleges, and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: How to you update the colleges?

Comment: @spickermann What do you mean by this?

Comment: You wrote the issue happens when updating a user with specific colleges. Therefore I wonder how you do that update, what do the parameters and the controller method look like?

Answer (score 0):

the syntax for Rails6 would be:

```rb
validates :college_id, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}
```

See [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)

I don't know if the older syntax is supported.

Comment: The syntax you suggest is only a shortcut that improves readability, but [`validates_uniqueness_of`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) is still available.